# Корни многочлена

Tags: алгоритм, полином

Интересуют алгоритмы поиска всех корней многочлена (включая комплексные).

Знаю, что есть метод 2D-приближений. А есть ли более эффективные алгоритмы?

Comment: Может вам поможет <a href="http://math.hashcode.ru/">Форум математиков</a> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно обобщить [метод Ньютона](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Метод_Ньютона) на случай комплексных корней, но есть опасность утонуть в [его бассейнах](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%9D%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0) :)

[Функция polyroots в MathCAD](http://window.edu.ru/resource/065/24065/files/chmeth.pdf) использует по умолчанию метод Лагерра, опционально - метод сопровождающей матрицы. Реализации этих методов встречал в сети.

Серьезные математические библиотеки реализуют [метод Дженкинса-Трауба](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins%E2%80%93Traub_algorithm) для уравнений общего вида. Метод обладает хорошей сходимостью (не хуже метода сопровождающей матрицы). А [здесь](http://www.srcc.msu.su/num_anal/lib_na/cat/cat41.htm) можно разжиться реализацией.

Очень интересен [метод Лобачевского-Греффе](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeffe%27s_method) (в западной науке традиционно занижают заслуги наших соотечественников, поэтому на английском следует искать по фамилиям Греффе и Данделена), позволяющий находить все корни одновременно. Только схема вычислений для комплексных корней довольно запутанная, реализаций не видел.

Еще пара ссылок на источники:
 1. [Тарасевич Ю. Ю. *Численные методы на Mathcad'е*](http://www.exponenta.ru/educat/systemat/tarasevich/preface_1.asp)
 2. [Трауб Дж. *Итерационные методы решения уравнений*](http://lib.mexmat.ru/books/843)